# Diagonal relation and reflexive relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let R be a non trivial relation on set X . If R is symmetric and anti symmetric then R is 
a ) reflexive
b ) transitive 
c ) equivalence 
d ) diagonal relation 
Actually I am confused about definition of diagonal relation i.e whether diagonal relation contains ( x ,x ) for every x  belongs to Set  or it contains ( x ,x ) for some x belongs to Set . And whether there is any difference between reflexive and diagonal relation ?

Answer (score 1):

Given that $R$ is simultaneously symmetric and antisymmetric, it follows that $R\subseteq\{(x,x)~:~x\in X\}\subseteq X\times X$

To see why this is:...

> suppose for contradiction that there was in fact some $(x,y)\in R$ where $x\neq y$.  By symmetry this implies that $(y,x)\in R$ as well.  By antisymmetry this implies that $(y,x)\notin R$.  These two observations contradict eachother.  This implies that there could not possibly be any pair $(x,y)\in R$ where $x\neq y$.

A reflexive relation is one where $\{(x,x)~:~x\in X\}\subseteq R$.  That is to say, it contains every possible pair of the form $(x,x)$ along with possibly containing other types of pairs too.

A diagonal relation is one where $R\subseteq\{(x,x)~:~x\in X\}$.  That is to say, it contains *only* pairs of the form $(x,x)$, possibly not all of them, and contains no other pairs of a different form.

It is possible for a diagonal relation to be reflexive and vice versa, but only in the case that the relation is specifically $R=\{(x,x)~:~x\in X\}$

We have as a result:

Regarding reflexivity:

> $R$ is not necessarily reflexive, but could be

Regarding transitivity:

> $R$ is transitive.  Since the only way that $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are elements of the relation is if $a=b=c$, it clearly follows that $(a,c)$ is also in the relation.

Regarding equivalence:

> As $R$ is not necessarily reflexive, it is again not necessarily an equivalence relation.

Regarding diagonality:

> $R$ is a diagonal relation

Comment: So if A = { 1 ,2 ,3 } then Relation on A ,denoted by R and given by R = { 1 } is diagonal relation. M I correct sir?

Comment: @alearner $R=\{1\}$ is not a relation on $A$.  $R=\{(1,1)\}$ is however.

Comment: Ohh! That was by mistake , so R = { (1, 1) } is diagonal relation on A ?

Comment: @alearner yes, $\{(1,1)\}$ is an example of a diagonal relation on $A$ which is simultaneously symmetric and antisymmetric as well as transitive but not reflexive.  Meanwhile $\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ is an example of a reflexive relation which is not diagonal, is transitive, is antisymmetric, but is not symmetric.